# @Transactional headaches with Spring-Data-Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm still relatively new to spring-data-neo4j, and while I've enjoyed interacting with it  for the most part, I've had some periodically-reoccurring problems with transaction management (using simple mapping) that I don't understand and that have been extremely  frustrating.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping("/{id}/posts")
    @ResponseBody
    public Set<POSTED> getPosts(@PathVariable Long id){
        //POSTED is a @RelationshipEntity-annotated class
        return userService.getItemsPosted(id);
    }
    //...
}
```

**Service interface:**

```
public interface UserService extends DomainService<User> {

    User load(long id);   //works fine
    User createNew(Map<String, Object> props);   //works fine
    Set<POSTED> getItemsPosted(User u);   //NotInTransactionException !!! 

}
```

**Service implementation:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired UserRepo repo; //standard empty interface extending GraphRepository<User>
    @Autowired Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User load(long id) {
        return repo.findOne(id); 
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Set<User> loadAll(int howMany) {
        Result<User> result = repo.findAll();
        Iterator<User> iter = result.iterator();

        if (!iter.hasNext()) throw new RuntimeException(" the result is empty!");
        User next =iter.next();

        HashSet<User> toret = new HashSet<User>();
        for (int i =0; i < howMany && iter.hasNext(); i++, next = iter.next() ) {
            toret.add(next); 
        }
    return toret;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User u) {
        template.save(u);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User createNew(Map<String, Object> props) {
        return repo.save(new User(props));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Set<POSTED> getItemsPosted(User u) {
        return template.fetch(u.posts); //NotInTransactionException 
    }
}
```

**Domain entity**

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("user")
public class User implements DomainNode {
    @GraphId
    Long id;
    //...
    @RelatedToVia
    Set<POSTED> posts = new HashSet<>();
    //...
 }
```

As is commented above, the only call that's causing a problem is `getItemsPosted()` - which happens to be the only method that makes a call on `Neo4jTemplate` directly: The other  methods, which also perform transactions, do so through calls to my `GraphRepository` and work fine.

Can I take this to mean that `@Transactional` simply does not apply to calls made on `Neo4jTemplate`? I know I can get around the exception by manually starting a transaction using `template.getGraphDatabase().beginTx()` - **my question is whether there's a better way to handle situations like this. I have this lurking feeling that I'm working against the framework in some way here that's making my life harder than it needs to be.**

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace, please? Also, post the code or xml config where you create the template and the tx manager.

Comment: I expect that it barfs on the `u.posts` call and not so much on the `template.fetch` call. Please post the full stacktrace for more information.